# UWP XAML Button disappears behind background when hovering over

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I have a number of buttons in my application structured as a side menu. They are placed inside a `RelativePanel`. If I give this `RelativePanel` a background color, my buttons disappear behind that color. I managed to solve that by modifying the foreground and background colors of the buttons themselves. However the issue persists when I hover over them. Like this:
[image]

If I remove the background color then the buttons behave correctly when I hover over them. Here's my XAML:

```
    <RelativePanel Name="RelativePanel_SidePanel" Width="200" Background="Black" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True">
        <Image Name="Image_Logo" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Square150x150Logo.png" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" />
        <Button Name="Button_Startpage" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="Image_Logo" BorderThickness="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#0780BA" Click="Button_Startpage_Click">
            <StackPanel>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Home" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="White" />
                <TextBlock FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="White">Startpagina</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

            <Button.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Button.Foreground>
        </Button>
    </RelativePanel>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  The mouseover style of your buttons is going to change the foreground of the content container to black (if in the light theme).  Obviously, black on black is not visible.  The default template for a button can be viewed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx).

If you're going to put the buttons on a black background, you can try to set the requested theme to dark as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.requestedtheme).  Alternatively, you can restyle the complete template of the button and handle the different states however you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these default themes. Very interesting, did not know that part of the site existed.